# How to enable Gadget resize

Tags: windows-7, windows-desktop-gadgets

If we look at out of the box Windows gadgets such as Weather , they include a button (apart from settings) which enables the resize of the gadget window.

Does anybody know how can I include this button my own gadget ?

I have built a custom gadget but does not have this small button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide onDock and onUndock handlers for the button to be seen. Please see

onDock event:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486201(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

onUndock event:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486205(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)